# jQuery Ajax Once There Are No More Results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm building a simple quiz for a client that's getting it's data from their database and I'm loading the questions with a Ajax call to get the next question after they answer the first one. That is all functioning fine but the problem I've run into is what would be the best method to check if there are no more questions, currently I'm using `success:` to replace the content with the next question and `error:` to replace the content with the end of quiz screen. If anyone could give me some advice on a better method it would be very much appreciated as I don't really want to use `error:` as in case there's an actual error with the Ajax call it would just say the quiz is done when I would want the user to be able to try the action again, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that would be something on the server side where you could return a value if there are no more questions, then check it on your success call.

Comment: What happens when you request a question which is out of the bounds ? What is the return value of the service you call ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
complete: function(data){
  if(data.length !== 0){
    // change question
  }else{
    // completed quiz
  }
}
```

then in your PHP, just return an empty json object when there are no further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help, I was trying that earlier but now I realize I was doing it with `success:` and not `complete:` haha I've been up for way to long now haha thank you very much!